# I need to retrieve 1.700.000 rows from SQL Server, then I need to write in XML file in C#

Tags: c#

I need to retrieve 1.700.000 rows from SQL Server and then I need to write those into a XML file. But it will so slow doing this in one time because the size of the file and there is close to 2 million rows over there, I thought I should read 1000 rows at a time and write them, and then read the next 1000 so on... without choking the system.

How can I create that kind of loop in C#? It would be great if I can get help with this. Thank you

Comment: Use paging to get the data and write to an XML stream.

Comment: This answer will largely depend on the data's contents, and how much memory is at your disposal.  If it's not important that the data is a couple seconds out of date potentially, you might consider using `no lock` hints on your sql as well, so it's not tying up the db while you're retrieving the data.  I'd highly suggest doing a little more research on how to address large data sets in places other than SO though, because this is something that's a pretty common issue, and pretty well documented other places.

Comment: You can also just use the SQL query engine to wrote the XML output and return the content.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your row size, but you might try the following.

As suggested by Matthew, consider using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) clause - it allows receving an already formed XML string as a result of SQL server query.

Also consider using the [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) instead of coding custom C# logic.

Thus, a complete solution could look like:

1). Create a scalar function that returns your XML,

```
CREATE function [dbo].[FunctionThatReturnsXML]() 
RETURNS varchar(max) 
as
BEGIN

DECLARE @ReturnStr Varchar(max);

SET @ReturnStr = (
 SELECT [yourColumn] as '@Column'
   FROM [yourQuery]
   FOR XML PATH ('Item'), ROOT ('Root')
 )
  RETURN @ReturnStr;
END
```

Here I use VARCHAR(MAX) although you might need to use TEXT. Also you could run the query directly from BCP (see next step) without the overhead of creating a function, but this makes it more neat.

2). Run a BCP command against your server (you should consider security and authentication here):

```
bcp.exe "select [dbo].[FunctionThatReturnsXML]()" queryout "C:\yourfolder\yourfile.xml" -c -T
```

The latter could be put it into a BAT file for reuse.